# Pycharm - modules belong to specific projects and not to all projects

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, intellij-plugin

I had been working with a older version of pycharm for a long long time, and recently I downloaded a new version.

My problem is that for every projects I open, I need to download all the modules that I'm using, meaning modules belong to project and not to pycharm. In addition, For every project I open, it's open a folder of the project for the code and another folder for the modules meaning for every project I got 2 folders, which is very very disappointing...

Someone have solution? I want to link the modules to my python and not to my projects...

Thanks a lot

Omer

By the way - my english is not my native language, please forgive me for any mistakes...

+++ It's also install me pip ( cause every project needs it's own pip :P every time im open project )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because in your PyCharm, when you create a new project, the interpreter is set to "New Virtualenv environment". Deselect this while creating your project and use the "Existing interpreter" for your project when you create one.

[image: PyCharm settings]

Make sure you have the right interpreter selected.

For installing modules throughout, you could just use `pip` on the command line.

Ideally though, I would recommend creating a virtual environment for each project, as is currently being done by PyCharm.